# How can I extract a page from pdf and put it into zip at the same time Python

Tags: python, sorting, pdf, zip, extract

I have script that does some sorting on files and produces a tuple that looks like statfiles = [filename1, filename2, felename3......].
Then I need to fetch a corresponding PDF for those files, extract one page from that file and create a zip file with all the pdfs processed. Right now I was only able to achieve that if I save an extracted page into separate (plots_ext) temp folder and then grab the files from that folder and put them into archive. I am sure it can be done without actually saving it into temp folder. But I am not that experienced in Python, so I am not sure how to achieve that task yet.

Here is the part of my code that does extracting/zipping task:

`pdfs = zipfile.ZipFile("hi_eff.zip","w"`)

```
for item in statfiles:

     output = pyPdf.PdfFileWriter()
     input1 = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(open('plots/'+item+".pdf", "rb"))
     output.addPage(input1.getPage(0))
     outputStream = open('plots_ext/'+item+".pdf", "wb")
     output.write(outputStream)
     outputStream.close()    

try:
    pdfs.write('plots_ext/'+item+".pdf")
except:
    print ('No PDF file for ', filename)

pdfs.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to replace outputStream with a StringIO object and the use ZipFile.writestr(StringIO.getvalue()) to write it out.

Comment: A bit confusing. So I just replace outputStream with StringIO and use  ZipFIle.writestr(StringIO.getvalue()) to write that page into archive?